# CSS: how can I apply scroll-snap-align only for anchor tags?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want the scrolling to snap to the scroll-snap-align points ONLY when clicking an anchor tag linking to a fragment, like this one `<a href="#my-work">See my work</a>`

I DON'T want the scroll snap to apply to scrolling with the mousewheel, because that would be annoying to whoever uses my website.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: No worries guys, I figured out my own solution with just 7 lines of JavaScript, comment if you want me to share it.

Comment: I see now this was a dumb question, all I want is smooth scrolling for when clicking <a> tags -.-, no scroll-snap-align needed, no js needed...

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make anchor tags when clicking to jump to a specific part of the page, you can try setting your anchor tags like this

```
<a href="#my-work">See my work</a>
```

and making sure the reference is same as the element you want the view to snap to:

```
<h2 id="my-work">This is the title for my work displayed</h2>
```

you can use also for images or paragraphs

```
<img id="my-work" src="/images/logo.jg"/>
```

Make sure you have one unique ID for one anchor tag.

Comment: I have it that way but I think you didn't understand my question. I want to scrolling to snap ONLY when using the anchor tags, and not when scrolling with the mouse wheel.